# Confused by plug?

Tags: usb

I brought my son a blue tooth speaker and it only came with a USB cable no plug. On the box where it says power suply it says power adapter 5.0v/1000mA in which kind of house plug that is I've no idea as I tried to charge it with my multi charging stand but within minutes the cable got really hot so I unplugged and I've no idea which type of plug to buy to go forward if anyone could help with my little issues I'd be so grateful much thanks sherrie x

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like either the cable or the speaker is broken and shorts the charger. Any standard USB charger _should_ work.

Comment: So a 5.0v/1000mA is any type of house plug? Or would it have to have a certain size fuse like a 3 amp or a 5 amp sorry I'm no good at these kind of things and it does not state on the instructions that came with the speaker hench my need of help sorry x

Comment: Please clarify exactly what got hot. The actual cable, or whatever plug/charger/power supply you had plugged it into. Post a picture of the underside of the charger if you're not sure what it is, so we can see any ratings info sticker it has underneath.

Comment: USB cable is getting hot from resistance [Ohm's Law] and would occur for one of three reasons, either: power source isn't rated for 5W [`V*A=W`], amp is trying to draw too much power [>5W] over the USB cable than the cable's wire gauge is rated to carry, or it's a defective USB cable. When it comes to USB cables in general, and especially when the cable is being used solely as a power cable, I've found it's best to buy from reputable manufacturers and always recommended [MonoPrice](https://www.monoprice.com/) since they manufacture and lifetime warranty their cables.

Answer (score 1):

Standard un-negotiated* power draw for USB 2 is 500mA. The speaker is trying to draw too much & either hasn't negotiated for a higher value or the charger simply cannot provide it; or [highly likely] one or both devices are incapable of negotiation at all.
Result, overheating [or fire!]

Look for a USB charger rated at 2.1A [a common value, easy to find in any supermarket.]
Just to be certain, monitor its temperature for a while. It will get warm but should never get hot.

*Negotiation requires a smart device such as a phone or pad, a fully-compliant USB **data** cable, not just a charger cable and also a charger that is capable of a) negotiating & b) actually giving the requested output. A smart device will simply charge more slowly if it cannot draw higher power, a 'dumb' device will just try to pull all the power. [Amps are *pulled* by the device, not *pushed* by the charger, so it's possible to 'pull too hard' for the charger.]

Comment: So what size amp fused plug would you suggest for me to use please as I'm literally no good with things like this sorry x

Comment: A charger that cannot provide more than 500 mA will not provide more. If there's heat, the heat is from these 500 mA or less (unless the charger is some cheap junk, without any fuse or so, and can actually provide more). But the OP wrote "the cable got really hot". The cable, not the charger; so there may be a short circuit in the cable. In such case 2 A will generate even more heat!

Comment: Sherrie - this is not a "fused plug" of any sort, this is a USB charger. I asked above - we need to know exactly what you've plugged it into ↑

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - [I've asked for clarification on cable/charger heating]  if you plug a 3KW electric heater into a 5A socket you will blow the fuse/trip the breaker. The fuse blows because it melts, because of the heat generated by asking for too much power from the circuit. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/26188 or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/464019

Comment: This answer is factually accurate: speakers are inputs and can't draw power, nor would a USB cable overheat from the amp sending too much power to a speaker _(it would be the internal leads from the amplifier soldered to the speaker's voice coil)_. The USB cable is getting hot from resistance [Ohm's Law], which would occur for one of three reasons, either: the power source isn't rated for 5W, the amplifier is trying to draw too much power [>5W] over the USB cable than the cable is rated to carry _(e.g. cable is of too small a gauge wire to power the amplifier)_, or it's a defective USB cable.

Comment: Any USB charger that's not absolute dangerous crap will handle overcurrent gracefully: it will limit output power to what they can safely provide and won't overheat. And a crappy dangerous charger would get hot itself (not the cable). If indeed the cable gets hot, it's a problem in the cable. Although at this point we should clarify the terminology first to make sure we understand the issue correctly.